# this part code is in cpp concurrency in action, but it still wrong, and i dont konw why, please

Tags: c++, concurrency

```cpp
typedef std::pair<Key, Value> bucket_value;
typedef std::list<bucket_value> bucket_data;
typedef typename bucket_data::iterator bucket_iterator;
bucket_data data;
mutable std::shared_mutex mt;
         
bucket_iterator find_entry_for(const Key& key) const
{
    return std::find_if(data.begin(), data.end(),
        [&](const bucket_value& item)
        {return item.first == key;});
}
```

the following picture is my g++ wrong message:
[image]

i try to ask the bing ai, but it couldn't solve my problem, and i reading the book agagin and again, and then i found out that my code didn't make ans mistankes, this is so unlucky.

Comment: Next time please post the **entire**, self-contained, relevant code. See [mcve]. But in this case the error is that your `bucket_iterator` is non-`const`. Change it to `typename bucket_data::const_iterator`.

Comment: sorry about that i cant post the entire, i am tring to figure out this how to use this web efficently

Comment: How can this website respond to your answers? I guess I'll have to explore for a while, but Konrad is right. I'll go and modify my code again

Comment: I can't find it in the errata for the second edition, but I believe the problem is that `find_entry_for` is const, so `find_if` returns a const iterator. Remove the trailing `const` from the function.

Comment: It's preferrable to post the error message as a code block too. This way you don't limit us to viewing the error message with the same viewport width as you...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.